# Fill in Input Field by Clicking Link - jQuery

Tags: jquery

How might someone fill in an input field with some text using jquery by clicking that text?

The text is generated dynamically so the value is not know ahead of time.

For example with:

```
<input id="tag" type="text" name="tags" value="">

<p>
    <a class="tag">aaa</a><br/>
    <a class="tag">bbb</a><br/>
    <a class="tag">ccc</a><br/>
    <a class="tag">ddd</a><br/>
    <a class="tag">eee</a>
</p>
```

I'm try with this

```
$('a.tag').live('click', function(e){
    $('#tag').val(this.innerHTML);
    return false; 
});
```

but this will put only one tag in the input field,  i need to put something like this

```
<input id="tag" type="text" name="tags" value="aaa, bbb, ccc, eee">
```

Here is working example
http://jsfiddle.net/Kaf3V/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a css class to keep track of selected links, so that you're able to remove links already added as well.

```
$('a.tag').live('click', function(e){

    // toggle selected class
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    // make a collection of tags
    var newTag = [];
    $('a.tag.selected').each(function(){

        // add value;
        newTag.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('#tag').val(newTag.join(', '));

    return false;  
});
```

See the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/Kaf3V/6/) for a demo.

**Note:** This only works if duplicates or the order that the links are clicked are not important.

Comment: Hello Goran, this just what i need, but what if i already have some tags in the input filed? Example http://jsfiddle.net/Kaf3V/8/ , so when i click to new one, old tags from input filed will be deleted ? I need to just fill with new one...

Comment: No problem, would it be feasible to add the `selected` class to the links in the HTML markup as they're generated. Like so - http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/Kaf3V/9/

Answer (score 0):

take the current value and add the new: `$('#tag').val( $('#tag').val() + this.innerHTML);`  you may want tto use a data array or even add .data() to the element to preventz this from adding the same value multiple times.